# Apps Script Trigger for IMPORTXML , OnChange / OnEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

I am currently in the middle of making a project, whereas data is being pulled from  website via IMPORTXML. I tried editing and searching for an answer to the question: how do I get a Timestamp in Column "AP" when there is data changed to Column "N" ? I've tried simple & installable triggers, but none seem to work.

[Link to the file (Spreadsheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZrKmm4oj1o3cuLNDYNKYZwI6Wrrxsfqt6o2BTMkQb7I/edit?usp=sharing)

I have never really had to use Apps Script for Google Spreadsheet, so I am sorry if there's some dumb coding there.

```
    function onChange2(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col == 14){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,42).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

> Didn't work

```
    function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange2')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();

        if(col == 14){
    source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,42).setValue(new Date());
    }  
    }

> No Luck here too
```

Comment: Functions and scripts do not trigger onEdit(), onChange().  So if IMPORTXML results in any change there is no way to tell.  What you could do is have checkbox somewhere and use onEdit() to examine whether the checkbox has been clicked.

Comment: Or another option would be a time driven trigger that compares values and if there is a different value do something.  The old value could be stored in the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en)